# AVAudioPlayer is not playing in swift. How to fix it?

Tags: swift, audio-player

In my app I want to integrate a AVAudioPlayer in my app. But I can`t here anything.
Thats my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class NotenAnsicht: UIViewController{


var PlaybackPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    PlaybackAudioAufsetzen()   
}




func PlaybackAudioAufsetzen(){

    do{

        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "mp3")
        try PlaybackPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        print("Song set")
    }
    catch{
        print("there was an Error")

    }

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@objc func PlaybayStarten(sender:UIButton){
    PlaybackPlayer.play()
    PlaybackPlayer.volume = 1
     print(PlaybackPlayer.isPlaying)
    print("Song should play")  
}


}
```

I have no idea where the problem is. All functions get called properly. And the audioplayer is not defined locally. After `PlaybackPlayer.play()`, `PlaybackPlayer.isPlaying` returns true. I just can`t here anything.

Do you have any idea where the problem is?

Comment: Is it device or simulator you have tried the code with.

Comment: I´ve tried it directly on my device....

Comment: set `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)` and 
        `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)`  in your `do` block before setting audioPath

Comment: @Quintus this code will make this app ready to takeover the device audio

Comment: @GovindKumawat Wow! You rescued my day! It works perfectly fine! Thanks!

Comment: @Quintus happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)` and `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` in your do block before setting audioPath.

your code should be look like that.

```
func PlaybackAudioAufsetzen(){

    do{

        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "mp3")

        /// this code will make this app ready to takeover the device audio
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        try PlaybackPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        print("Song set")
    }
    catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```